# Is there a Chromium/Firefox plugin to tell how many times I visited a website?

Tags: web-browser, statistics

I am looking for any Chromium or Firefox extension which gives statistics about which websites you visit.

For example, it should show me today from 8:00 to 12:00 PM, how many times I visited *face.com*?

Comment: You could use a webfilter for this. Lol. But I don't think this is what your looking for although I am pretty sure k9-web protection kind of does this.

Comment: @アズーサ LoL nice I will try that

Comment: @alex- I might have a look for an extension for you though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well also adding to @ATG's answer there is another way you can do this in Firefox but it only displays how many times you visited the website on that day only.

1. On Firefox, Right click on the page (E.g. Google)
2. Click on "View Page Info"
3. Head over to "Security"

and it should look something like this:

[image]

or this most of the time:

[image]

Also feel free to resize the images if you want. Didn't know how to do that by the way.

Answer (score 4):

There's something pretty close to this already available in Firefox history.

If you do a `Ctrl + Shift + H` it should bring up the full browser history in a pop-out window.  Then, you can right-click on the table column header row (where it probably says "Name", "Location" and "Most Recent Visit" by default) and choose to display the "Visit Count" column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Google Chrome extension [timeStats](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/timestats/ejifodhjoeeenihgfpjijjmpomaphmah?hl=en), it has some nice statistics but the free version seems to have some ads now so you might want to use adblock at the same time:

> - Daily statistics – Showing the statistics of websites visited by day
> - Monthly statistics – Showing the statistics of websites visited by month
> - Visited sites – Taken from the complete statistics about your browsing.
> - Site statistics – Showing how much time you spend on certain website during the time you have Time Stats installed.
> - Time spent – Showing the total amount of time you spend browsing each day
> - Most visited domains – The complete list of the most visited domains from the most visited to the least visited
> - Most Busiest days – The days you spend the largest amount of time browsing the web.
> - Categories: You can sort your websites into the categories, which you can name by yourself.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox I use free [**Mind the time**](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/mind-the-time/) addon.

- Show statistics, how many minutes user see pages of site;
- Daily, weekly and monthly statistics;
- [**Grey, Green and Blue mode**](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/mind-the-time/).

[image: Mind the time]

But Mind the time not show exact time of site visited, this extension not suitable for alibi :).

---

---

I do not know why it took you an extension, but usually questions, like the one that asked you, ask if want to increase personal productivity. Therefore, in this answer I write about the extension, which I use in tandem to Mind the time.

If you want to block time-wasting sites that can suck the life out of your working day, I recommend free [**LeechBlock**](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/leechblock/) addon. All you need to do is specify which sites to block and when to block them. I saw in Mind the time addon sites, who take my working time, and add it to LeechBlock list.

[image: nervov page block]

Some options:

- Grouping time-wasting sites. For example, Music sites, social networks, sports sites for me. For each group I can do a variety of settings.
  [image: LeechBlock 1]
- Block site not forever, but only in some time. For example, I block go to the time-wasting sites only in my working time: 06:00 — 12:00 and 13:00 — 17:00. You can also specify which days to block sites.
  [image: LeechBlock 2]

LeechBlock have many other options, you may read it in [**official site of addon**](http://www.proginosko.com/leechblock/).